# Java: Unicode is not converted correctly to text by graphics.drawString(...)

Tags: java, graphics, unicode

I am trying to get generate image of text in different languages.

For that I am using the following code:

```
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200, 60, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Color.PINK);
    graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    graphics.drawString("ट्रेल्स", 20, 40);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputStream);
```

But the image generated by above code is [image]

The text in the image is a bit different from `ट्रेल्स`

The reason for the above mismatch is that the unicode characters for `ट्रेल्स` is `\u091f\u094d\u0930\u0947\u0932\u094d\u0938` and if we convert each unicode number to its corresponding character, we get exactly the same text as in the image.

So I think `graphics.drawString(...)` is doing it's job correct.

But as the output is not the expected one, So how to get around this?

Any pointers to `textToImage` api will also do.

Comment: What platform are you on? What version of Java?

Comment: I am on Mac OS X. Java 1.7.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a rendering bug in Java. Let's see if anyone else turns up. You could try Java 6.

Comment: That's 'rendering'. drawString is not implementing the full Unicode rendering rules, and I can't tell you why.

Comment: `drawString` doesn't support complex text layout. Try a [TextLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html).

Comment: @bobince Tried `draw` of `TextLayout` also but it's also not working. Output is same as that of `drawString` of `Graphics`

Comment: Maybe a font problem? I don't think plain `Arial` has glyphs for Devenagari, so maybe you're getting a fallback font that doesn't have the glyph combining substitutes? What happens if you go straight to a known-good font (eg `Mangal` under Windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the problem.

As correctly pointed out by @bobince also, the issue was with the font `Arial` which I was using.

To render a text of a particular language, the font should have glyphs for that language to correctly render the text.

e.g For rendering hindi text, fonts like `Mangal`, which have glyphs for hindi language, will render the text correctly.

The same hindi font will work for Marathi language also since the glyphs remains same for both languages but won't work for languages like Tamil, Telugu etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using different font such as MONOSPACED or SansSerif

```
Font font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 11);
graphics.setFont(font);
graphics.drawString("ट्रेल्स. रीकदोसै. जोकालन्त", 1, 10);
graphics.dispose();
```

where the I have used java.awt.Font class. This worked and the characters were represented correctly.